# What is the real life use-case of the applicationContext.getBean() in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

The *applicationContext vs beanFactory* seems to be very popular job interview question.
Is there any real use case to call `applicationContext.getBean(foo.class)` or `beanFactory.getBean(foo.class)` explicitly in Spring Boot?

I have read some tutorials explaining the difference between ApplicationContext and BeanFactory, but I still don't see the real use-case. Why would any developer call `getBean()` explicitly?

Comment: In certain configuration classes (when you need collaborators and injecting them would cause too early instantiation) or when the `ApplicationContext`/`BeanFactory` is used as a factory for instances of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) is the parent interface that exposes all the basic methods of the spring container, which are closely related with `beans` (getBean(), containsBean(), isPrototype()...)

Here a common scenario where it could be used, is for example in the main static method that spring boot starts, in case you want to do some action after the initialization of spring container has finished. Considering that you are inside a static method autowiring will not work. But with this `BeanFactory` you are able to manually do such action.

Example

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        BeanFactory beanFactory = SpringApplication.run(ServiceLauncher.class, args);
        //At this point the Spring Beans Context has been loaded
        Activity activity = beanFactory.getBean(Activity.class); //So we are able to retrieve from the context a bean to do in this static class some more actions.
        activity.doSomething();         
    }   
}
```

[ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) is an interface extending the above `BeanFactory` interface. It could be used again in the above scenario, but the reason it exists is that it exposes some more useful methods which could provide some extra functionality when needed. More commonly used are some interfaces that extend the `ApplicationContext`. Example the [ConfigurableApplicationContext.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html)

Here common scenarios used are the `refresh()` of applicationContext,
`close()` which closes the application context and also the registering of a shutdown hook when terminating with `registerShutdownHook()`.

Basically the `registerShutdownHook()` is commonly used because when the JVM is asked to terminate maybe you want to do a graceful shutdown, where the application context will not be closed immediately but will give you some control during shutdown.

```
@Component
public class Activity implements DisposableBean {

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Destroying Activity component shutting down!!!");
    }
}
```

and you register the hook with

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ServiceLauncher {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {            
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context   = SpringApplication.run(ServiceLauncher.class, args);
            context.registerShutdownHook();         
        }   
    }
```

Those are just some of the most common uses I have seen in several applications and projects. But each separate method exposed by some interface could have it's own use case and that's why it exists there. I am confident though that just for interview questions, the interviewer will have in his mind the above 2 scenarios.